# Hide navigation bar but remember the history in wpf frame

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a frame on my main window. I have an ItemsControl in which I show the vertical menu from which user can select any Item and the page corresponding to specific Item is shown in the frame.

This works well.

When I set NavigationUIVisibility to Automatic:

```
1) Navigation Bar is displayed at the top.
2) If I enter some data in a textbox in page1 and then if I navigate away to page2.
   Now again if I navigate to page1, the text in the textbox is there.
```

What I want is:

```
1) Hide the Navigation bar. For that I have set NavigationUIVisibility to Hidden.
   This works good.
2) I want frame to remember history as I discussed in point 2 in above topic.
   So, How to remember history when NavigationUIVisibility is set to hidden.
   Or is there any other way to remember history when navigation bar is hidden.
```

Comment: I suspect `Text` is retained only in case when you navigate via `navigation bar` but if you navigate using code, textBox text won't be retained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-style `NavigationFrame`s and `NavigationWindow`s so that they look completely different. In fact all of these images below are `NavigationWindow`s, even the one without any navigation UI at all.

[image]

I put together an open source library for re-styling these at http://winchrome.codeplex.com so you can just steal the parts you need from the style. In fact if you just want a navigating panel with menu on the left, then its already covered in some of the demos for that project.

---

To answer your question as to why the `TextBox` clears it depends very much on what you are navigating to, and for some cases this is independent of the history.

Lets start simply, lets consider we have MyPage.xaml

```
<Page x:class="MyPage"...>
  <TextBox/>
</Page>
```

- If you are navigating to the same `MyPage` that you were before, then it will still have the same values in it.
- If you are navigating to a `new MyPage()` then by default the `TextBox` will be empty.
- If the navigation history is turned on, and you are navigating back, then you get the original `MyPage` and so see the same value in the `TextBox`.

Now lets consider if we are using MVVM style views bound to ViewModels.
In MyPage.xaml

```
<Page ...>
  <TextBox Text="{Binding MyData}"/>
</Page>
```

In DataViewModel.cs

```
public class DataViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string myData;
  public string MyData 
  {
    get { return myData;} 
    set { ... }
  //Normal implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged etc for MVVM
}
```

- If you are navigating to a `new Page()` which is bound to the same `ViewModel` then both `Page`s will always be in sync and show the same data.
- If navigating to the `ViewModel` and relying on `DataTemplate`s to create a view, then you have still have two views but both sync from the same ViewModel.
- If you use the history and navigate back, you get the original `MyPage` so see the original data again.

Answer (score 1):

The [Frame class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.Frame%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a property called [BackStack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.backstack%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which retains the back navigation history for a Frame. This property is available to you regardless of the NavigationUIVisibility setting.

Answer (score 1):

Use PageFunction instead, which helps out you to navigate very backward retaining values for that pages..

Page1.xaml:

```
<PageFunction
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
    x:Class="XYZ"
    x:TypeArguments="sys:String"
    Title="page1">

    <TextBox x:Name="textbox"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Click="button_clicked"/>

</PageFunction>


private void button_clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Page2 page2 = new Page2();
     page2.Return += page2_Return;
     this.NavigationService.Navigate(page2);
}

void page2_Return(object sender, ReturnEventArgs<String> e)
{
    OnReturn(new ReturnEventArgs<String>(null));
}
```

Page2.Xaml:

```
<PageFunction
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
    x:Class="PQR"
    x:TypeArguments="sys:String"
    Title="page2">

    ...


</PageFunction>


void BackButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OnReturn(new ReturnEventArgs<String>(null));
}
```