# Navigating between pages contained in a Window

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation

My question is if there's a more elegant solution for navigating between pages that are contained in a Window than searching that Window and changing it's content.

This's how I did it:

```
Page1 a = new Page1(param);
Window parent = Window.GetWindow(this);
parent.Content = a;
```

My thought is that if there are Navigation tools already implemented I should be using them, instead of doing that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Navigation Service of the page as follows:

GoTo **Page2** From **Page1**.

```
Page2 p2 = new Page2();
this.NavigationService.Navigate(p2);
```

Also the better way is to use Page Function instead of Page.

See My answer for the Page Function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450758/hide-navigation-bar-but-remember-the-history-in-wpf-frame/20537692#20537692)

or refer [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa349685(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried the first method, but it launched a NullPointerException, indicating that the NavigationService was null. And i'll check Page Function, thanks.